# recover node from unhealthy

Tags: hadoop, nodes, hadoop-yarn

I am using *HDP 2.3* and it's my 4th time when I am trying to import with *sqoop* a large database ( *aprox. 200 million rows* ) but my active node becomes unhealthy and the process is unsuccessful.

> The health-report: 1/1 local-dirs are bad: /hadoop/yarn/local; 1/1
>   log-dirs are bad: /hadoop/yarn/log

I want to add the fact that, before installing sqoop, I had repositories issues with ambari.repo and sandbox.repo and I have disabled them from the `/etc/yum.repos.d` folder.

Please help!

Many thanks!
Andrei